# Theano - logistic regression example weight vector becomes NaN?

Tags: logistic-regression, theano

I am doing a tutorial (code [here](https://github.com/Newmu/Theano-Tutorials/blob/master/2_logistic_regression.py)) and video [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S75EdAcXHKk) (13:00 minutes in).

My only change is using the mnist training set from a different location (creating a one-hot encoding) but it is not working.  I literally copy-pasted all the code (except for the mnist loading) in this example.  Here is the code:

```
import theano
from theano import tensor as T
import numpy as np  
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_mldata
mnist = fetch_mldata("MNIST Original")
trX, teX, trY_digit, teY_digit = train_test_split(mnist.data, mnist.target, test_size=.4)

#Get one-hot encoding
enc = OneHotEncoder()
enc.fit([[n] for n in range(10)])
trY, teY = sparse_to_floatX(enc.transform(trY_digit[:,newaxis])), sparse_to_floatX(enc.transform(teY_digit[:,newaxis]))

def floatX(X):
    return np.asarray(X, dtype=theano.config.floatX)

def init_weights(shape):
    return theano.shared(floatX(np.random.randn(*shape) * 0.1))

def model(X, w):
    return T.nnet.softmax(T.dot(X, w))

X = T.fmatrix()
Y = T.fmatrix()

w = init_weights((784, 10))

py_x = model(X, w)
y_pred = T.argmax(py_x, axis=1)

cost = T.mean(T.nnet.categorical_crossentropy(py_x, Y))
gradient = T.grad(cost=cost, wrt=w)
update = [[w, w - gradient * 0.05]]

train = theano.function(inputs=[X, Y], outputs=cost, updates=update, allow_input_downcast=True)
predict = theano.function(inputs=[X], outputs=y_pred, allow_input_downcast=True)

for i in range(10):
    print w.get_value()
    cost = train(trX, trY)
    print i, predict(teX)
```

The weight vector updates once, and becomes all `NaN` on the second update.  I am very new to theano, but I am looking for tips to figure this out, especially if someone has already done this tutorial.

**UPDATE**.
It looks like the gradient is the issue.

When I add this

```
the_grad = T.sum(gradient)
f_grad = theano.function(inputs=[X, Y], outputs=the_grad, allow_input_downcast=True)
print f_grad(trX, trY)
```

It prints `NaN`.  This appears to be the correct usage of `T.grad` though.

**UPDATE 2.**
When I change the cost function to this:

```
cost = T.mean(T.sum(T.sqr(py_x - Y), axis=1), axis=0)
```

It is working now but I only have 70% accuracy which is really bad.

**UPDATE 3.**
I downloaded the MNIST data used in the tutorial and it worked with 92% accuary.

I am not sure why my first mnist datasource was dying with the crossentropy cost, and then performing really poor with mean squared error cost function.

Comment: The provided code doesn't run as-is so it's difficult or impossible to diagnose the problem. In particular, the `train_test_split` and `sparse_to_floatX` functions are not provided. Can you please provide executable code that demonstrates the problem?